# Wired connection keeps shutting down randomly Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

So I have a machine that I use as a server to host some apps for development purposes (to lighten up my laptop), it runs Ubuntu 18.04.

When I SSH in it, the network cuts randomly after some time (sometimes a few seconds sometimes it can take a lot more time). This causes me to restart my ssh connection. I am trying to troubleshoot the network but I do not know where to look, I used this desktop machine a few months ago for development and gaming and this never happened to me. I doubt that it is a hardware issue (but it can be).

Since I don't know where to look to troubleshoot this kind of issues, here's some information about my network interface:

```sh
seraf@seraf-server:~$ ifconfig
enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.86.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.x.x.x
        inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe3a:ddc5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:85:c2:3a:dd:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 132668  bytes 60666040 (60.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 112  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 135126  bytes 39778416 (39.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfe700000-fe71ffff
```

```sh
seraf@seraf-server:~$ lspci -knn | grep -i -A 10 eth
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
```

Let me know what other information you want

Comment: You're getting rx errors. Is this a server or desktop installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and your make/model# of the computer... if this is a custom build computer, then edit your question with `sudo dmidecode -t 1,2`.

Comment: @K7AAY if you do some investigation BEFORE switching around the hardware, you'll have a better clue... for example... my `lshw` command will tell me if there's a cable problem, or connection problem, or some other network problem.

Comment: Since the problem was described as random, the result of a command at any given moment may or may not find the problem; hence the suggest to perform a cable replacement which would perform consistantly.

Comment: It was indeed a cable issue, how noob. Thanx guys, I'm closing this.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a cable issue, I changed my Ethernet cable and it was all fixed, as suggested in the comments of the question.

I did not know that a cable could make data transfer intermittently disconnect at random intervals, I thought it should either work or won't.